# Map one Scala case class with a certain structure to another with a different structure

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am building a Scala API that talks to **Elasticsearch** using [Elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s).

One response I receive from Elastic4s is of the type [SearchHit](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-http/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/http/search/responses.scala) and has the structure:

```
SearchHit(id: String,
          index: String,
          `type`: String,
          score: Float,
          private val _source: Map(name: String,
                                   code: String,
                                   location: Map(lat: Double, lon:Double)
                                  )
          )
```

I need to map this object to another object of the structure:

```
case class Location(id: Option[String] = None, location: GeoLocation, code: String, name: String)
```

where `GeoLocation` is:

```
case class GeoLocation(lat: Double, lon: Double)
```

As you can see, most of the fields I need to be mapped to `Location` are inside the `_source` Map but I also need the `id` to be mapped.

Comment: What does `Map(lat: Double, lon:Double)` mean? Use the latitude as a key to look up the longitude value? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: You can give https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney a try

Comment: @jwvh `location` is a `Map[String, Double]` but I know that in the response I will get something like a `Map(lat -> 43.65, lon -> -79.39)`. I wrote it like that for simplicity. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Why is `_source` private? You can't access it outside of `SearchHit` class this way.

Comment: @Dima nvm that. It's part of the **Elastic4s** library. There is a getter `sourceAsMap` that returns the `_source`

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic4s provides a typeclass that will help. It's called `HitReader` (although it might change name in version 6 - to be released), and if you implement this for your type `Location` then you can call `.to[T]` on the search results.

```
object LocationHitReader extends HitReader {
  def read(hit: Hit): Either[Throwable, T] = ...
}
```

Implementing this by hand doesn't get you much further than where you are at the moment, but elastic4s then provides implementations using the common json backends - Jackson, Json4s, Circe, Spray-Json so you don't have to do anything.

If you use *Jackson* for example, then you add `elastic4s-jackson` to your classpath and then add the following import above your search results.

`import ElasticJackson.Implicits._`

Then, on your search result, you can call `.to[Location]` to get a `Seq[Location]` or `.safeTo[Location]` to get an `Seq[Either[T, Location]`

To get the id out as well, you could create a custom `HitReader` which delegates to the library created one, adding the id.

Comment: I changed the `id` parameter on my Location case class to a `var`: `case class Location(var id: Option[String] = None, location: GeoLocation, code: String, name: String)`. Then I'm using the `.to[Location]` method and then adding the id to Location. I didn't want to have a mutable parameter but it works for now.

Comment: That's one way. The other way is to have your id field, and populate it with an id, as well as the elasticsearch id field (so in the data you'd have _id and id). It's an extra field but avoids the var.

Comment: The id should be unique. Is there a way in Elasticsearch to make sure that another document with the same id cannot be created if I use my own id?